# Bind multiple SSLs on single website in IIS 8+

Tags: iis, ssl

I have one website configured for Windows Server 2012 IIS 8. This one website can be accessed by xyz.com or abc.com (2 different top level domain names).  Is it possible to configure SSLs for both?

Answer (score 42):

Yes. You can configure two different domains with two different certificates for the same IP and port no(443). After providing the domain name in Binding, enable check box Require Server Name Identification(IIS8). If you do not enable this check box, two websites will have the same single certificate, if you change one website binding file, it will reflect in other website also.. I have experienced.

Please refer below link.
http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/fred/host-different-ssls-on-one-ip-with-iis-8-sni/

Comment: link is not working

Answer (score 1):

As Windows Azure web site is powered by IIS, you can see from the offerings that it is possible to bind multiple SSL to a single site,

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/web-sites/#web-sites

The trick is to use SNI,

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-server-name-indication-sni-ssl-scalability

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add multiple https bindings each with their own separate ssl certificate to the same site in IIS. However you'll want to bind them to separate IP addresses so that the certificate for xyz.com is bound using the IP address for xyz.com, and the certificate for abc.com is bound using the IP address for abc.com. But frankly, it'd be better practice to have one redirect to the other, or just make 2 sites in IIS and keep everything separate.

Comment: This only applies to the old IP based SSL. Since IIS 8, SNI SSL has been supported, which finally eliminates the above restrictions.

Comment: Unfortunately SNI doesn't work on Windows XP, and we still come across folks who are still on XP.

Comment: It would be wrong to say "Windows XP" as a whole, as Firefox 2+ and Chrome 6+ on Windows XP support SNI. Besides, Windows XP is now end-of-life, which means it's no longer a platform we should pay much attention to. IIS 8+ allows combination of IP SSL and SNI SSL, so at least the IP SSL can be used for non-SNI browsers.